# Android Studio Electric Eel, preview render problem when using custom font

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, kotlin, preview

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></View>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This problem has started from Android Studio Dolphin and I'm still facing this with Electric Eel.

For me, I'm facing this problem when I'm using custom fonts on my project. If i remove fontFamily attribute from my xml file, preview renders again...

If I remove font family, preview works..

```
android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
```